# Display additional fields on forms (External lists)

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, external-list

I have a external list where I have employee information. I am trying to do a lookup where I can select the employee and display it's corresponding department with the additional columns possibility.

I have noticed that lookup columns to this list don't display the additional columns in the display form. It does in the view of the list though.

This behavior does not happen with Lookup columns to regular lists: the display form shows the additional columns (not the edit form of course) and the view as well.

Is there anyway to fix this? I am working with SharePoint 2013